# Android query battery stats context issue

Tags: android

So I have a method that queries for the battery stats. I have no issues when I do this using the activity context, but if I used the context from a broadcast receiver I get

> android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: IntentReceiver
>   components are not allowed to register to receive intents

If I can't register for a receiver using a broadcastReceiver context, how would i work around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> If I can't register for a receiver using a broadcastReceiver context, how would i work around this?

If you only want the most recent battery information, pass `null` instead of a `BroadcastReceiver` to `registerReceiver()`, which will return the most recent sticky `Intent` that had been broadcast.